# debug php applications without apache or iis

Tags: debugging, netbeans

I have a development environment on windows 7 that eventually gets pushed to Arch for testing/staging and and then to production.

Aside from production of PHP web applications, my desktop carries many other duties and I would like to keep it as streamlined as possible.

Is it possible to write and debug PHP application using NetBeans (my preferred IDE) withot the use of Apache?

If so, can someone lead me to some documentation to help me make this a reality?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to debug straight out of Netbeans.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html